# Prometheus promQL query is not showing 0 when metric data does not exists

Tags: prometheus, promql

Considering the simple promQL:

```
sum(metric_name{label="some label value"}) by (label, another_label)
```

I get this graph displayed:
[image]
I know that my `metric_name` has data for two label values for `another_label`, e.g. `another value1` and `another value2`, but only the line for `another value1` is displayed, because for this time interval, there is/might be no data for `another value2`.

What I want to achieve is to see the second line for `another value2` displayed as 0.
I tried:

```
sum(metric_name{label="some label value"} or on() vector(0)) by (label, another_label)
```

No luck, then I tried with a trick:

```
sum(
  metric_name{label="some label value"} 
  or (absent(metric_name{label="some label value", another_label="another value2"}) - 1)
) by (label, another_label)
```

This worked as expected:
[image]
But as you can imagine I don't want to manually chain these `absent` conditions for every existing label value of `another_label`, especially that I know that these won't be just two in reality.

1. Can I somehow generalize the `absent` condition like `or (absent(metric_name{label="some label value", another_label="<foreach>"}) - 1)`?
2. Is there some other way to fill these gaps with 0?

Answer (score 0):

> because for this time interval, there is/might be no data for another value2

This is the main problem. First of all, try to always have values for each of you metric from the moment the application starts. It will solve most of the problems. For example, if you have metric `my_app{status="up|down"} 0|1` for displaying the app status you always need to update its both labels when status changes:

```
app is down:
  my_app{status="down"} 0 => 1 
  my_app{status="up"} 1 => 0

app is up:
  my_app{status="down"} 1 => 0
  my_app{status="up"} 0 => 1
```

If you have these metric updated as I described you won't face the issue you described.

But I understand it is not always possible to do "how in books". In this case take a look at `default` function from [VictoriaMetrics MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html):

```
"default" binary operator. q1 default q2 fills gaps in q1 with the corresponding values from q2.
```